# sql lite syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been figuring out this for an hour but not sure what the error is:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
,phone TEXT
,NAME TEXT
,contact_id TEXT
,photo_url TEXT
,sts INTEGER CHECK (
    sts IN (
        '0'
        ,'1'
        )
    ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
)
,spam INTEGER CHECK (
spam IN (
    '0'
    ,'1'
    )
) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' )
```

I am getting `syntax error near near ","`.

Can anyone point out what I am missing there ? Thanks

Comment: Probably unrelated, but numbers should be specified without single quotes. `'1'` is a string, `1` is a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) <-- remove this
,spam INTEGER CHECK (
spam IN (
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find this very hard to read.  Try it this way - I think it makes spotting mismatches between parentheses and commas easier.

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  phone TEXT,
  NAME TEXT,
  contact_id TEXT,
  photo_url TEXT,
  sts INTEGER CHECK (sts IN ( '0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'),
  spam INTEGER CHECK (spam IN ('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0')
)
```

Comment: While you pasted code that will probably work, you didn't say why the original code didn't work. Please explain the difference as well.

Comment: I think it's hard to read; easy to make an error like extra comma or paren.